# Using deltaTime

Tags: java, android

I got deltaTime calculated as 2.7855414E8 on my tablet. How do I get speed for specific device, calibred by deltaTime? For example, if I need object with moving speed, which is about reaching half device screen size per 1 second?

Edit: delta calculation

```
timeStart = System.nanoTime();
deltaTime = (timeStart - oldTimeStart) / 1000000;
oldTimeStart = timeStart;
```

Comment: How do you calculate delta?

Comment: Edited main post.

Comment: You should divide by 1'000'000'000, not 1'000'000. If delta is calculated correctly, it should return ~16.7 at 60fps. This means if you want to move a object 3 units per second, you would multiply delta by 3

Comment: The reason to divide by 1 billion, is because a nanosecond is a billionth of a second. 1 = 1000ms, 1ms = 1000μ, 1μ = 1000ns. Your calculation would fit a microsecond resolution, but not a nanosecond resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Ostensibly, `deltaTime` is measured by units of...time e.g. seconds, meaning the device itself is irrelevant for that.

What you want is to multiply by the number of pixels in the device's screen (or some fraction thereof).  You'll have to look up how to get that yourself, but it's probably something like `Screen.width` or `Screen.screenWidth` (I've only done android and ios development in Unity, not Java so I do not know the appropriate class that has what you need).

For example, to move across the screen in 2 seconds and assuming that position is measured in device-pixels, you'd do this:

```
onUpdate() {
    pos.x += Screen.Width/2 * deltaTime;
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks. But although I used this calculation, it still returns a large number, should I divide it more or?

Comment: Well, seeing as a nano is 1/1,000,000,000 of a second and you're multiplying by 1,000,000...